# Sub-divide features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, features

I am new at QGIS and GIS in general. Basically, I have a shapefile of continents. However, I need to include further refinements. For example, within "Oceania", I need to identify New Zealand and New Guinea. How can I create a new feature that identifies "New Zeland" while it is no longer one of the polygons identified as "Oceania"?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your shapefile and attribute table?

Comment: Yes, just included

Comment: Looking at your dataset, I would recommend to obtain a countries boundary file, which is easily accessible. The current file you have, contains only 7 features (representing each continent). The process you are looking for is to clip the country boundary of New Zealand and have a new feature. This is possible with some editing. However, I'm not sure if it worth the time to do that versus just getting another dataset. If you want I can link you a dataset or I can try to go through the steps of what you want to do here?

Comment: While it's trivial to dissolve smaller polygons into larger ones, is quite difficult to manufacture new data from nothing. This case is only not impossible becase the country boundary perferctly aligns to island boundaries, but you'd still need to determine which islands make up the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download shapefiles from the link at the bottom for New Zealand and Papa New Guinea. Choose the "Administrative Areas" and unzip the contents. Load into QGIS and copy the features you want into your main shapefile.

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata